# Execute Javascript-File with Button click in d3

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, d3.js, execute

i have a d3 graph in node.js. In this Graph i'm calling

```
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
      //execute another js-file and reload the graph
}
```

What i want to do is: On Click of updatebutton i want to execute another javascript file (wiki.js) and after that reload the graph(like a reload in webbrowser).

Is this possible? I would be happy about some help! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add a script element to the head:

```
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
      //execute another js-file 
     var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
     scriptElement.onload = function(){
        //and redraw the graph
     }
     scriptElement.src = "wiki.js";
     document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
})
```

Comment: so in my function above i simply call scriptElement.onload = function (){//refresh here} ?

Comment: You have to include all the code in your function, if you want to load a file on click. In the onload callback you can redraw graph, it will be executed if the file is loaded.